# How to properly escape a user agent for blocking in htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, web-scraping, user-agent, blocking

I'm trying to block 1 specific user that is constantly scraping my site by hand. He uses a VPN, so IP blocking doesn't work. I can't seem to get him blocked via my HTaccess file. I'm using the following code which is the escaped version of this user agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36 OPR/65.0.3467.48

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Chrome version 0\.0 running on Win10 Mozilla\/5\.0 \(Windows NT 10\.0; Win64; x64\) AppleWebKit\/537\.36 \(KHTML, like Gecko\) Chrome\/78\.0\.3904\.97 Safari\/537\.36 OPR\/65\.0\.3467\.48" bad_bot
Deny from env=bad_bot

</IfModule>
```

Does this make any sense? I don't want to block too many other users with this piece of code, but I'm afraid that user agent is quite common.

Thanks in advance!

Ps. This goes way beyond my knowledge, but feel free to drop in any technical solutions or language and I'll figure it out with a dev friend.

Comment: Technically what you are trying to do is blocking a very common `user-agent` Which is really bad ! The best solution is to capture the request for viewing page source and block it ! Or disable page source view !